# React build app on docker using nginx wont affect changes of .env file after build

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

docker-compose

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - website:/usr/share/nginx/html/website
  client:
    image: client
    stdin_open: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    volumes:
        - website:/website/build/
        - ./client:/website
        - /website/node_modules
volumes:
    website:
```

nginx Docker

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 999M;

location / {
         root /usr/share/nginx/html/website;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     }
}
```

react Docker

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /website
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
```

`npm run build` uses `vite` to build.
It creates my react app and everything works fine and if I change something in my app and call
`sudo docker container exec erp_client_1 npm run build`
to build app again it changes it the way it should be, but when I change `.env` file it won't affect changes after npm run build my variables stays the same.
`.env` file is in client folder like every other file for build.

Comment: I have volume:./client:/website. When I change in my root folder client.env file, it automatically changes in the container webiste folder from where it builds my react app. I checked that and it changed, but when it builds, application variables stay the same.